# Extrair documentos pdf de sites com scrapy

Tags: web-scraping, scrapy

É possível varrer um site inteiro passando em todos os links em busca de arquivos pdf com scrapy? seria algo parecido com o apache nutch. Eu fiz uma pesquisa mas o pessoal só usa XPath, e XPath não dá pra min pq eu tenho que entrar em vários sites para fazer a pesquisa e fazer um crawler para cada site é humanamente impossível.

obs:

Eu tenho que baixar os pdf(s);

Eu tenho que passar varias url(s) para o crawler.

Comment: Qual a linguagem que você trabalha?

Comment: Boa tarde, André. Eu trabalho com php mas eu acho que com o scrapy seria mais rápido já que é uma aplicação pra fazer crawler.